# Finding Boroughs with Geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I'm using the Geocoder gem for my rails project and there's one small problem I seem to be running into. I have a user model that has an `address` attribute. This attribute stores information as follows:

```
geocoded_by :address do |obj,results|
  if geo = results.first
    obj.state = geo.state
    obj.country = geo.country
    obj.city = geo.city
  end
end
```

This works just fine but if I try to enter an address with a borough, geocode only returns the city. So for example if I try to save `Brooklyn, New York` it will return `New York, New York` but if I enter a town such as `Middletown, Delaware` it has no problem displaying its full location. Is there a parameter I can use to query boroughs? I've tried `geo.borough` but got errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't very many borough's in the US (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borough_(United_States))).

As you probably know, Brooklyn, New York is in New York, New York so the fact that the city data responds with New York is 100% accurate.

That said, I do see `The Bronx` in an sample call I made to the google maps api here:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=610+Waring+Ave,+Bronx+NY

```
[2] pry(main)> HTTParty.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=610+Waring+Ave,+Bronx+NY')

=> {"results"=>
  [{"address_components"=>
     [{"long_name"=>"610", "short_name"=>"610", "types"=>["street_number"]},
      {"long_name"=>"Waring Avenue", "short_name"=>"Waring Ave", "types"=>["route"]},
      {"long_name"=>"Bronx",
       "short_name"=>"Bronx",
       "types"=>["sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"Bronx County",
       "short_name"=>"Bronx County",
       "types"=>["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"New York",
       "short_name"=>"NY",
       "types"=>["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"United States", "short_name"=>"US", "types"=>["country", "political"]},
      {"long_name"=>"10467", "short_name"=>"10467", "types"=>["postal_code"]}],
    "formatted_address"=>"610 Waring Avenue, Bronx, NY 10467, USA",
    "geometry"=>
     {"location"=>{"lat"=>40.861204, "lng"=>-73.870415},
      "location_type"=>"ROOFTOP",
      "viewport"=>
       {"northeast"=>{"lat"=>40.8625529802915, "lng"=>-73.8690660197085},
        "southwest"=>{"lat"=>40.8598550197085, "lng"=>-73.8717639802915}}},
    "types"=>["street_address"]}],
 "status"=>"OK"}
```

You can see in [this file](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/lib/geocoder/results/geocoder_us.rb) that they're not currently supporting anything but those params.  Maybe a pull request is in order as this feature would be good for me as well.

Comment: Thanks for heads up. I'm actually playing around with those params right now but as you probably know from just at first glance, things get very long winded. How would you recommend attaining the borough and letting Geocoder handle the rest (in terms of returning the correct city, state, country) based on the `geocoded_by` method I have now? I'm not even sure if I should create an entirely new attribute for boroughs but as you said there aren't that many to begin with.

Comment: Ya, you would need to patch Geocoder.  I submitted an issue on github to see if it's something they plan to support.

Comment: 1+ for the feature request on GitHub as well. Its much appreciated.

Comment: Feature request was turned down @CarlEdwards.  If I were you, I'd get a list of zip codes for the borough's you care about and if your `obj.zipcode` contains one of those zip codes, update the model to include a borough.   Make sense?

Comment: Kind of. Can we continue this in a chat?